# ¿Como negar un grupo palabras en especifico? angular CLI

Tags: regex, angular-cli

**Problema**
Haciendo uso de validator.pattern angular CLI verifique que en las siguiente cadenas no exista alguna de las siguientes palabras: perro, gato.

**Resultado esperado**
el perro ladra: false
el gato maulla: false
el perro ladra al gato: false
el canino ladra al felino: true

Expresión regular a usar:
^(?!.*perro).*$

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: El regex está bien, ¿Cuál es la pregunta?